# Is the vanilla version of the Snap-Store able to deal with .deb and apt?

Tags: apt, snap, deb

Acording to sources like this:
[OMG! Ubuntu!: Ubuntu Switches to a Snap’d Software Store for 20.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-snap-store-transition#:%7E:text=The%20repackaged%20Ubuntu%20Software%20%E2%80%94%20which,capable%20of%20fwupd%20firmware%20updates.)
It seems like the **Snap Store** (renamed as **Ubuntu Software** in Ubuntu 20.04) is able to install **.deb** files and provides `apt` support.

I assume this is valid for the ubuntu *flavour* of the Snap Store:
`snap install --channel=stable/ubuntu-20-04 snap-store`
or
`snap install --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-20-04 snap-store`

But, is it still valid if you install the *clean* version of the application? i.e.
`snap install snap-store`
or
`snap install --channel=latest/stable snap-store`

Is the "vanilla" version of the **Snap-Store** able to dea with **.deb** and `apt`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different software apps in Ubuntu 20.04, Software [image] and Snap Store [image]. The Snap Store and the Software app can be installed alongside each other without removing either app.

Snap Store is a graphical desktop application for discovering, installing and managing snaps. The vanilla version of the Snap Store is not able to deal with deb packages and apt. All the apps in the Snap Store are snap packages. If you're searching for a snap package it's more convenient to search for it in the Snap Store, because sometimes the same app has two packages in Ubuntu Software, an apt package and a snap package, but the same app has only one snap package in the Snap Store.

Comment: The Software app can be installed from the terminal in 20.04 by running `sudo apt install gnome-software`.

Answer (score 0):

And then there is [Ubuntu Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgQ9O.png), @Karel (sorry, I can't yet comment on your answer).

Ubuntu Software is the default store in Ubuntu 20.04, it's not Sofware nor vanilla Snap Store.